# resizable Canvas or panel in scrollpane

Tags: java, awt

I want to create java applet having Canvas or Panel. Now when i start entering data using drawstring(), height of Canvas or Panel should increase dynamically and scroll bar should be visible.

How can I implement such applet?

Please let me know even this can be achieved by using control other then Canvas or Panel.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use Swing.  Why paint the text when a `JTextArea` or `JEditorPane` can paint it easily?

Drop the `JTextComponent` into a `JScrollPane`, put that in a `JPanel`, add the `JPanel` to a `JApplet`.  Job done.